Acer ES1-512 Laptop Won't Even Turn On After RAM Replacement
I have an Acer ES1-512-C88M Laptop that I am trying to upgrade it's RAM. The first time I put the new RAM in there, it worked for a 2 or 3 restarts, but after leaving it on sleep mode for about 2 hours, the next time I turned the computer on, the light just turned on and that was it. The default RAM was a Samsung PC3L-12800S 4GB RAM, and I have replaced it with an 8 GB PC3L-12800S SODIMM RAM, but whatever I try, the old RAM works, but not the new one. After a few "Googling", I went and replaced the CMOS battery, but that made it worse. Now the computer doesn't even turn on. Any ideas of how to get it back to normal but with RAM replacement? PS: Both of them have the same voltage, 1.35 volts. I know about how RAM incompability works, but I have checked this RAM throughly and it seems to work as it should. I have read the post about RAM incompability, and that doesn't answer my question at all, I want to find out why isn't this RAM that works for my computer not working.

Your RAM doesn't fit your motherboard. Return it and next time be more careful.

Oh, but I fitted in there perfectly, and it worked for 2-3 times. How is it not going to fit?

"Fit" means more than "can be inserted".
